# Regular expression to allow decimal places including .123 and 123. etc in Java

Tags: java, regex

Friends

I have the following Regex `"^[0-9]{1,12}+(\\.[0-9]{1,4})?$"` that allows the following values

123456789012.1234 which is a valid decimal value {12,4}

123456789012 which is a valid integer value etc

but **it doesn't allow value like .1235 etc** , how should I modify above Regex so that it also allows values like **.123 and 123.** etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess,

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,12}(?:\\.[0-9]{0,4})?|\\.[0-9]{0,4})$
```

might be somewhat close.

#### TEST

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

                
        final String regex = "^(?:[0-9]{1,12}(?:\\.[0-9]{0,4})?|\\.[0-9]{0,4})$";
        final String string = "123456789012.1234\n"
             + "123456789012\n"
             + ".1235\n"
             + ".123\n"
             + "123.\n"
             + ".12345\n"
             + "0.12345";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Full match: 123456789012.1234
Full match: 123456789012
Full match: .1235
Full match: .123
Full match: 123.
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GIdBEY/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/GIdBEY/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Emma what does ?: mean

Comment: Excellent , Thanks you Emma